# Unable to create external cache directory

Tags: android, java

Почему не работает код?

Умею скачивать данные с сервера. Осталось научится делать так, чтобы они подгружались порциями в зависимости от прокрутки экрана. На сервере лежит JSONArray. Его считываю по частям, но что-то не очень получается(

Вот что написал:

```
public class Main extends ListActivity {

    // откуда начинать считывать данные
private int from = 0;
    // количество считываемых данных
private int number = 10;

private ListView listView;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    listView = (ListView)findViewById(android.R.id.list);
    ItemAdapter adapter = new ItemAdapter();

    setTitle("List of search engines");

            // Считываем первую порцию данных
    MyTask mt = new MyTask();
    Log.d("AsynsTask - MyTask", "create MyTask: " + mt.hashCode());
    mt.execute();

    listView.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener() {

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollState) {}

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {

            if (view.getAdapter() != null && ((firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount) >= totalItemCount)){

                from = totalItemCount;

                MyTask mt = new MyTask();
                mt.execute();
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    });     
}

class MyTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> {

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {

            // Здесь происходит считывание данных json и парсинг
        rsj = new ReadStringJson("http://ed.sadko.mobi/askdroid.web/api?action=engines_list_by_alphabet&from=" + from + "&number=" + number);
        try {
            parsingFunction(rsj.readFromServer());

        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Log.e("IOException: ", ex.toString());
        } catch (JSONException ex) {
            Log.e("JSONException: ", ex.toString());
        }    
      return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

А вот и логи

> `11-04 11:13:20.302: I/Choreographer(819): Skipped 69 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
> 11-04 11:13:21.882: W/ImageLoader(819): Unable to create external cache directory
> 11-04 11:13:22.132: W/ImageLoader(819): Unable to create external cache directory
> 11-04 11:13:22.372: D/dalvikvm(819): GC_CONCURRENT freed 232K, 4% free 8182K/8519K, paused 152ms+88ms, total 333ms
> 11-04 11:13:22.402: W/ImageLoader(819): Unable to create external cache directory
> 11-04 11:13:22.612: W/ImageLoader(819): Unable to create external cache directory
> 11-04 11:13:22.712: W/ImageLoader(819): Unable to create external cache directory
> 11-04 11:13:22.792: W/ImageLoader(819): Unable to create external cache directory
> ...`

Как-то так получается, что после прокрутки не подгружаются новые данные(

Comment: А что за ошибка то? Покажите Log хотя бы

Comment: ИМХО лучше на сервере написать функцию, которая будет отдавать данные "постранично", запрашивать номер страницы, и получать именно ее...

Comment: ну вот нет возможности реализовать это дело на стороне сервера...
Тут то что можно сделать?

Comment: Попробуйте добавить в манифест:  

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />